# Creating a PHP Web Server Based on CentOS 8 with Docker

Tags: docker, centos

Here is my Dockerfile to create a simple web server based on CentOS 8:

```
FROM  centos:8

RUN yum -y update && \
yum -y install httpd php

COPY . /var/www/html                                                                                                                                  



CMD ["httpd", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

I build and run the container with the following commands:

```
docker build -t web .
docker run --rm --name web -p 8000:80 --network net1 --mount type=bind,source=`pwd`,target=/var/www/html web
```

The error I see when accessing http://localhost:8000 is:

> Service Unavailable
> The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

The httpd logs say:

```
[Sat Jun 20 04:42:02.970003 2020] [suexec:notice] [pid 1:tid 140041021270272] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.19.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Sat Jun 20 04:42:02.994125 2020] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 1:tid 140041021270272] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sat Jun 20 04:42:02.995333 2020] [http2:warn] [pid 1:tid 140041021270272] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[Sat Jun 20 04:42:03.001899 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1:tid 140041021270272] AH00489: Apache/2.4.37 (centos) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jun 20 04:42:03.002120 2020] [core:notice] [pid 1:tid 140041021270272] AH00094: Command line: 'httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Sat Jun 20 04:42:04.782201 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 8:tid 140040377865984] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php-fpm/www.sock (*) failed
[Sat Jun 20 04:42:04.782280 2020] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 8:tid 140040377865984] [client 172.19.0.1:41072] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS
```

The problem is not as clear to me as it seems. I think it's a php-fpm issue, but have no idea how to fix it. Looked this up, but all solutions seem complicated. Is there a simple way to tell PHP to work with the server in the Docker image?
I recently read about using process managers like supervisord where one needs to start several services per container. But, is it possible to start PHP-FPM in a simpler way inside the web container?

Answer (score 3):

I managed to tackle it when using a base rhel 8 image by

```
CMD ["bash", "-c", "/usr/sbin/apachectl start; /usr/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize"]
```

But when I tried it with base centos 8 image, it doesn't work, I don't know why